# No Profile for WebDriverAgentRunner is seen on java scripts , but works fine when AgentRunner is build from xcode

Tags: java, ios, xcode, appium, appium-ios

I did setup my machine for Appium 1.6.3 to work on Mac -iOS.
Did follow the steps mentioned in the Github appium

- When i run WebDriverAgentRunner from **xcode it builds and succeeds**  without any error.
  Also when i **used the command: It works fine**, without any error, see the  logs for this Below.

xcodebuild -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination id=f0217f5ae1b2d491485727122a1abf2fa96baee5 test

- Also i was **able to install the IntegrationApp** on the actual device and also the webDriverAgent was also installed
- Now when i try to run **my scripts for automation using eclipse, i get the Error saying**  - Also see the logs for this below

"Testing failed:
    No profiles for 'com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunnersRS' were found:  Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunnersRS'.
    Code signing is required for product type 'UI Testing Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'
** TEST FAILED **"

===**Logs from the webDriver Agent Runner**=====

```
  Check dependencies

writeDictToFile:1278 ==== Successfully wrote Manifest cache to  /var/folders/05/79kfthm94qjd3bngd2l5pv7r0mx69v/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/All/Xc ode/EmbeddedAppDeltas/b9586745e5d50e5f0ab67fe98cee6082/86f963c77c0b8d2654fc1d0f6 8035e401c5d07a9/ManifestCache.plist
Test Suite 'All tests' started at 2017-03-24 11:39:27.539
Test Suite 'WebDriverAgentRunner.xctest' started at 2017-03-24 11:39:27.540
Test Suite 'UITestingUITests' started at 2017-03-24 11:39:27.541
Test Case '-[UITestingUITests testRunner]' started.
t =     0.00s     Start Test at 2017-03-24 11:39:27.542
t =     0.00s     Set Up
      ^C** BUILD INTERRUPTED **

NCA1005547:WebDriverAgent gangaiahl$ export    DEVICE_URL=http://10.65.212.72:8100
NCA1005547:WebDriverAgent gangaiahl$ export JSON_HEADER='-H "Content-Type:  application/json;charset=UTF-8, accept: application/json"'
NCA1005547:WebDriverAgent gangaiahl$ curl -X GET $JSON_HEADER   $DEVICE_URL/status
  curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
 curl: (6) Could not resolve host: accept
  curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
 {
   "value" : {
   "state" : "success",
   "os" : {
   "name" : "iOS",
   "version" : "10.2"
  },
   "ios" : {
   "simulatorVersion" : "10.2"
 },
    "build" : {
    "time" : "Mar 24 2017 11:13:50"
  }
 },
   "sessionId" : "6D9969E1-0D7E-4C96-AA20-58FC6CB4C864",
  "status" : 0
   }   NCA1005547:WebDriverAgent gangaiahl$export      DEVICE_URL=http://10.65.212.72:8100
 NCA1005547:WebDriverAgent gangaiahl$ export JSON_HEADER='-H "Content-      Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8,accept:application/json"'
  NCA1005547:WebDriverAgent gangaiahl$ curl -X GET $JSON_HEADER           $DEVICE_URL/status
    {
       "value" : {
      "state" : "success",
        "os" : {
       "name" : "iOS",
       "version" : "10.2"
     },
       "ios" : {
       "simulatorVersion" : "10.2"
    },
     "build" : {
      "time" : "Mar 24 2017 11:13:50"
    }
    },
     "sessionId" : "6D9969E1-0D7E-4C96-AA20-58FC6CB4C864",
      "status" : 0
        }NCA1005547:WebDriverAgent gangaiahl$
```

----------**Logs from the Automation scripts using eclipse**------

```
      UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Test operation was canceled. If you   believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at   /Users/gangaiahl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent- brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Logs/Test/40AEE85C-87C1-4815-8797-  22A0E34FD2AE/Session-WebDriverAgentRunner-2017-03-24_114756-8X5AAG.log}

     [Xcode] 
    Testing failed:
    No profiles for 'com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunnersRS' were found:  Xcode     couldn't find a provisioning profile matching    'com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunnersRS'.
    Code signing is required for product type 'UI Testing Bundle' in SDK 'iOS     10.2'
    ** TEST FAILED **


  The following build commands failed:
  Check dependencies
  (1 failure)

 [XCUITest] xcodebuild exited with code '65' and signal 'null'
 [XCUITest] Error: xcodebuild failed with code 65
 at SubProcess.<anonymous> (../../lib/webdriveragent.js:355:25)
  at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
  at SubProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
 at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (../../lib/teen_process.js:197:14)
 at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
 at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
 at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
 Error: xcodebuild failed with code 65
 at SubProcess.<anonymous> (../../lib/webdriveragent.js:355:25)
 at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
 at SubProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
 at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (../../lib/teen_process.js:197:14)
 at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
 at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
 at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
[XCUITest] Shutting down sub-processes
[XCUITest] Shutting down Logger process (pid 2203)
[XCUITest] System log exited with code '0'
[debug] [XCUITest] Reset not set, continuing
[debug] [iOSLog] Stopping iOS log capture
 [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: xcodebuild       failed with code 65
at SubProcess.<anonymous> (../../lib/webdriveragent.js:355:25)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at SubProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (../../lib/teen_process.js:197:14)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
   [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 6790 ms - 167
```

Comment: Hi .. have you configured apple developer account in xcode which contains provisioning profiles for this app ?

Comment: @HarshGoyal Yes its been added, Any other suggestions pls. Dam i need to get this error resolved

Comment: @HarshGoyal Finally it worked.....Writting down here b'c it might help others as well -- MAKE SURE - you have the webdriveragentrunner and all other associated file with it (WebDriverAgentLib , WebDriverAgentUSBClient and Unittest , IntegrationTests and IntegrationApp) all use the correct developer signed . This is Under General->team. When i say developer signed the https://developer.apple.com/account -user should be able to login and get it signed from there and u are using the same signed account

Comment: Nice man .. i was trying to told u the same.

Comment: thanks man ,yes i kind of did it ,but it was not when u told me